# If statement in ruby seems to give only the else result

Tags: ruby, if-statement

As said in the title, whatever result I set as input, it always gives the else's result which means F.
I've spent some time searching why, but I can't figure it out.
I'm used to Java as a language and I'm just starting ruby, so I'm trying to code accordingly to what I know in Java and maybe this might be the mistake.

```
class Test
  @g1
  @g2
  @g3
  @avg
  @grade
  def initialize(g, gg, ggg)
    @g1 = g
    @g2 = gg
    @g3 = ggg
  end

  def setAVG
    @avg = (@g1.to_f + @g2.to_f + @g3.to_f)/3.0
  end

  def getScore
    if @avg.to_f >= 90 and @avg.to_f <= 100
      @grade = 'A'
    elsif @avg.to_f >= 80 and @avg.to_f <= 89
        @grade = 'B'
    elsif @avg.to_f >= 70 and @avg.to_f <= 79
      @grade = 'C'
    elsif @avg.to_f >= 60 and @avg.to_f <= 69
      @grade = 'D'
    else
      @grade = 'F'
    end

    @grade

  end

end

puts 'Enter g1'
gr1 = gets()

puts 'Enter g2'
gr2 = gets()

puts 'Enter g3'
gr3 = gets()

gradesArr = [gr1, gr2, gr3]

for g in 0..gradesArr.length
  if gradesArr[g].to_f <0 or gradesArr[g].to_f > 100
    puts "Reset program with correction at the #{g+1} grade"
    abort
  end
end

grObj = Test.new(gr1,gr2,gr3);

puts "YOUR GRADE IS:  #{grObj.getScore}     #{grObj.setAVG}"
```

Also feel free to tell me if these are the ruby standards, for example, I know that in java you generally type return for a get method, but in ruby, you just write the variable.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Print out the value of `@avg` and run the code; my guess is that the value isn't what you think it is.  Or, debug your Ruby script.

Comment: `@avg` is not set at the time `.getScore` is called. Call `.setAVG` before you call `.getScore`.

Comment: ...wow thanks to you I remembered that the code was supposed to call setAVG before the is statement, but looks like I forgot what I wanted to do in process of typing of typing it       THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: Also, thank you for the suggestion of printing the result, I totally didn't thought about it

Comment: You can remove all the lines between `class Test` and `def initiailize` - they do nothing.

Comment: Regarding your code: (1) those `@g1`, `@g2` etc. at the beginning of the class are superfluous – they don't have any effect. (2) use better variable names – `g`, `gg` and `ggg` are awful. (3) use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` for method names and variables. (4) avoid `get` and `set` prefixes. (5) don't convert "just in case" – `@avg` is a float, calling `to_f` is not only needless, but also masks a bug (`@avg` being `nil`). (6) don't use `and` instead of `&&` – they are not equivalent. (7) avoid "low-level" loops like `for`, use `each` instead (or in your case `any?`).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler class that you can implement:

```
class Test

  attr_accessor :scores

  def initialize(*scores)
    @scores = scores
  end

  def average
    scores.sum / scores.size
  end

  def grade
    case average
    when 90..100 then "A"
    when 80...90 then "B"
    when 70...80 then "C"
    when 50...70 then "D"
    when 0...50  then "F"
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
t = Test.new(78, 88, 92)
t.average #=> 86
t.grade #=> "B"
```

Tips:

- use `attr_accessor` for read/write access to class variables
- only store what you need to save
- utilize `case` statements instead of long `if/else` statements

Note: For Ruby versions < 2.4, use `scores.reduce(:+)` instead of `scores.sum`.

Comment: * Avoid variable names like `g`, `gg` and `ggg`

Comment: `sum` isn't available on `Array` in older versions of Ruby (before 2.4). Some frameworks, such as Rails, do define it though. An alternative if `sum` isn't available is `inject(:+)`.

Comment: Your ranges overlap slightly, e.g. both `90..100` and `80..90` match `90` which could cause a bug later on. You should use `80..89` or `80...90` instead.

Comment: Should an average round? e.g. is an 89 and a 90 a 90 or an 89 because generally I would assume that the benefit is given to the student on a `.5` but ruby makes no such distinction on integer math.  e.g. `(89 + 90) / 2 #=> 89` which can make the difference of a grade point.

Comment: I agree with you, but this was intended to be sample code, the OP can add a `to_f`

Comment: First of all, thank you for the corrected answer. It makes me realize that I have a lot of basic to restart since I did them according to java style.               Second, I still encounter a problem, the sum method does not work. I tried and searched for the inject method, but still no better success. Here is the code for the average method: `scores.inject(0) {|tempo, total|tempo+total } / scores.size`  and it gives me this error: `String can't be coerced into Fixnum`.  I believe that the constructor sets the scores to strings, but how can I convert them. Is there an `to_f` to add somewhere?

Comment: I added a note with how to sum prior to the `sum` method, which was added in Ruby 2.4. To force floating-point division instead of integer division, you can add `to_f` to `scores.size.`